# initialization of circular queue in Omnet

Tags: c++, queue, omnet++

I am new to Omnet and am having some difficulty in initializing `circular queue`. I think this is done in the same way as initialization is done in `C++` but I am not so sure. For instance, when I have a variable int numbers. I initialize it by `numbers = par("numbers")`. Similarly, I have a circular queue `cQueue queue`. Now, how would I initialize it? I didn't find any useful documentation for this. I want to initialize queue to an empty array. Something like `queue=[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Sadiksha.

This is not the best place to ask about Omnet++. When you have more doubts, go to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/omnetpp

Either way, I'll try to answer your question ;)

You got some things mixed up. The `cQueue` class is not a circular queue, but a simple queue for storing pointers to objects of the cObject type. Also, for initializing an empty queue, you just need to declare it, like

```
cQueue queue("Named Queue"); // creates a named queue
```

You can then add default objects to your queue using a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    queue.insert(obj); // get this object somewhere
}
```

I hope this helps.

Regards